# Why `mapDispatchToProps` does not see `stateProps`?

Tags: redux, react-redux

## Intro

The signature of `mapDispatchToProps` is:

`mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps`

One could wonder, why `mapDispatchToProps` is not provided also with `stateProps` i.e. the result of `mapStateToProps` call. The alternative syntax could be such as:

`mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps], [stateProps]): dispatchProps`

It seems to me that this does not break anything (not even the performance) and can be beneficial in some situations.

## Question

Is there any reason why this is not implemented? Am I missing something? How would you solve the use case presented below without this feature?

## Why it does not break anything

Such change would allow user to customize `dispatchProps` functions with `stateProps`. When `stateProps` change, React-Redux can recompute `dispatchProps` with the actual `stateProps` and rerender the component. Such logic already happens with the `ownProps`

## Performance

If user does not need to read `stateProps`, they can omit the argument in their `mapDispatchToProps` implementation. React-Redux can detect this and assume, that `dispatchProps` are not dependent on `stateProps`. Such performance tweak is already implemented for `ownProps`.

## Use case

Say I have 10 action(creator)s that deal with a specific todo item. These 10 actions looks like:

```
changeTitle(todoId, title) {
  return {
    type: 'changeTitle',
    todoId,
    title,
  }
}
// etc...
```

If all 10 action(creator)s need `todoId` one it might make sense to make a partial instantiation of the action(creator)s (It can be written even more succinctly but that's not relevant now):

```
actionsForTodo(todoId) {
  return {
    changeTitle: (title) => ({
      type: 'changeTitle',
      todoId,
      title,
    }),
    // more action(creator)s here
  }
}
```

and then simply provide `todoId` for all action(creator)s:

```
mapDispatchToProps((dispatch, ownProps, stateProps) => 
  bindActionCreators(actionsForTodo(stateProps.todoId)))
```

Comment: If your action need to access `stateProps`, you should have already `mapStateToProps`ed, and the `todoId` would then be passed as the actionCreators argument.

Answer (score 3):

This *would* actually negatively affect performance quite a bit.  Since the result of `mapState` is a function of the store state and possibly the component's own incoming props, this would require `mapDispatch` to be re-run every time the output of `mapState changes`, and almost definitely result in new function objects being allocated every single time.  That would be a waste of CPU cycles in almost all cases.  it's much simpler to simply pass in item-specific values as arguments when you call these functions from the component.

There *is* a supported workaround: the third argument to `connect()` is a `mergeProps` function, which *does* get the the output of `mapState` and `mapDispatch`, and can customize how they're merged together.  If that use case really matters to you, you can implement the logic yourself by providing a `mergeProps` function.

That said, the upcoming React-Redux@5.0.0 prerelease version is a major rewrite of the implementation, which *does* now have a new `connectAdvanced` function that supports this type of scenario better.  See https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/pull/416 .

Comment: <quote> this would require mapDispatch to be re-run every time the output of mapState changes </quote>

If user doesn't need such feature, they can not use the `stateProps` argument, `mapDispatch` can detect this and behave the 'old way'.

If user need such feature, creating a few closures on some renders may be quite negligible cost comparing to the more readable code.

The workaround you're proposing is exactly what I'm using right now. It feels like hacking and I would like to get rid of it :)

I'll definitely check React-Redux@5.0.0, thanks :)